# \seq_get:NN vs \seq_get_left:NN

Tags: latex3

In the l3seq module of LaTeX3, there are similar functions such as

- `\seq_get:NN` and `\seq_get_left:NN`

They both store the left-most (top) item from the `<sequence>` into the `<token list variable>` without removing it from the `<sequence>`. So what's the difference between them?

Comment: [Absolutely nothing](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/25ad3179576253c5b503b6b4bc5922684a2420fe/l3kernel/l3seq.dtx#L2531)

Comment: the first has five letters less to type, but is not so clear in the naming.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to look at the source code. Thank you@MaxChernoff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Semantics: `\seq_get:NN` would be used with a `seq` where you never 'care' about the order, only that it is ordered. `\seq_get_left:NN` would be used if you are explicitly determining which end of the `seq` to push/get from.